# socket implement in the thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

i have to read some data from database and send it from a tcp socket
so i fetch data from database

```
    #main
    while True:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE `raw` SET `zombie`='"+zombieId+"' WHERE result='pending' AND protocol='tcp' AND zombie='0' LIMIT 1;")
#       time.sleep(0.2)
        cursor.execute("select * from raw WHERE `result`='pending' AND `protocol`='tcp' and `zombie`='"+zombieId+"' limit 1;")

            if cursor.rowcount>0 :
                    waitedSig = cursor.fetchone()
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    t = threading.Thread(target=sendData , args=((waitedSig),))
                    t.start()
                    time.sleep(0.6)
            else:
                    time.sleep(1)
```

on the thread i will send data to target

```
    def sendData(sig):
        timedata = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(sig[16]))
        devimei = sig[23]
        devdate = timedata.strftime("%d%m%y")
        devtime = timedata.strftime("%H%M%S")
        lat= format(sig[2])
        lon= format(sig[3])
        satcount = format(sig[5])
        speed = format(sig[4])
        batery = format(sig[7])
        if sig[9]>1000:
                band='00'
        elif sig[9]>850:
                band='02'
        else:
                band='01'
        hdop  = format(sig[10])
        gsmQ =  format(sig[6])
        lac =  format(sig[12])
        cid =  format(sig[13])
str='$MGV002,'+devimei+',12345,S,'+devdate+','+devtime+',A,'+lat+',N,'+lon+',E,0,'+satcount+',00,'+hdop+','+speed+',0,,,432,11,'+lac+','
            try:
                    clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                    result = clientsocket.connect(('ip',port))
                    clientsocket.send(str)
                    data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
                    print(str(datetime.datetime.now())+' -> send completed :'+format(sig[0]))
                    clientsocket.close()
            except:
                    print(str(datetime.datetime.now())+' -> connection to tcp server failed!!')
```

this will work  really good but there are two boring problem:

1) if i remove `0.2` and `0.6` sleep delay the script crash due to duplicate socket usage,it seems system try to open an other socket until the previous don't finished its job yet!

2) if some thing goes wrong in the `sendData` function,the whole script stop working until i manually restart the script

**so**

**1) can i create a thread queue to run one after other and don't affect each other?!**

**2) how can i handle errors in the thread function to close just that specific thread and script continue its work with next database record?!**

Comment: _the script crash due to duplicate socket usage_ does that mean there is a stack trace? Can you post that stack trace?

Comment: Your loops are odd. You query for everything, send the first thing, query for everything again, send the first thing again.

Comment: I don't see how you get duplicate sockets, except you don't shutdown the socket before close in the thread. `clientsocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)`.

Comment: @tdelaney no,i cut the code for avoiding misunderstanding.first i update one roq with a worker id the worker select its row and try to send it with the `sendData` thread.this help me to rum unlimited worker to send data.

Comment: @tdelaney i used `clientsocket.close()` at the end of thread you mean i must add  `clientsocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)` too !?

Comment: You don't have to show your real code, but you have to show something that makes sense. For instance, `clientsocket.send(sig)` can't work because `sig` is a list.

Comment: Yes, you need to shutdown the socket. They are strange beasts indeed. On some operating systems, sockets can be inherited by child processes so close == shutdown would be a bad thing.

Comment: I don't know what a duplicate socket error is. Can you posted the error python showed you so that we can see it too.

Comment: @tdelaney you are right , i submitted my complete code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good application of a thread pool. In your implementation you create one thread and socket per item in your database table, and that could tax the system extremely. Here I've created 20 workers as an example. There are diminishing returns on the number of workers as you start to stress the system.

```
import multiprocessing.pool

def sender():
    pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(20) # pick your size...
    cursor.execute("select * from database")
    pool.map(sendData, cursor, chunksize=1)

def sendData(sig):
        try:
                clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                result = clientsocket.connect(('ip',port))
                clientsocket.sendall(sig)
                data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
                print(str(datetime.datetime.now())+' -> send completed :'+format(sig[0]))
                clientsocket.shutdown(socket.SOCK_RDWR)
                clientsocket.close()
        except:
                print(str(datetime.datetime.now())+' -> connection to tcp server fa
```

Comment: Um, port busy? That's likely a question of how the server is configured. It does a `listen` with a count of the max number of allowed pending connections. It doesn't do much good to have a pool larger than what the server accepts. You can catch that error, sleep a few seconds and try again. That will help pace naturally with what the server can do.

Comment: my mistake.i deleted comment because port busy error is occur when we listen to a socket and other program try to listen to that port too.i will test your provided code and update here..thank you for helps.